# Get 'basename' from 'glob'

Tags: perl, glob, basename

Directory path "/home/PPP/main/windows/agile/cmPvt" has aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd as its contents.

Code Snippet:

```
use File::Basename;
my $kkLoc = ("/home/PPP/main/windows/agile/cmPvt");
my @kkarray = glob("$kkLoc/*") if (-e $kkLoc);
foreach my $kknum (@kkarray) {  ## Here: see below
}
```

Here: here I want that in `@kkarray`, `"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"` shall come, but I am getting the whole path like `"/home/PPP/main/windows/agile/cmPvt/aaa", "/home/PPP/main/windows/agile/cmPvt/bbb",....` Also, I tried, `foreach my $kknum (basename "@kkarray") { }`, but not working.

How can I get the "basename" from the full path while doing `glob()`?

Note: I can't do `chdir` to the path before executing `glob` command due to a reason.

Comment: What is this "a reason"?

Comment: Note that `my ... if ...;` is non-sense and now allowed. You want `my @kkarray = -e $kkLoc ? glob(...) : ();`

Comment: Note that your code suffers from a code injection bug. You need  to convert the directory name into a glob pattern. `glob("\Q$kkLoc\E/*")` would work on unix. No easy way on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map) to call `basename` on each element of the array:

```
foreach my $kknum (map { basename($_) } @kkarray) {
}
```

This keeps the full path in the array variable, if that is desired.

If you never want the full path in the array variable, you can use `map` when you populate the array:

```
my @kkarray = map { basename($_) } glob("$kkLoc/*");
```

Answer (score 3):

You tried to use a string with the interpolated array as argument to `basename`. That is wrong. You should take the individual paths, not all the paths concatenated together.

```
for my $path (@paths) { 
    print "Basename is: ", basename($path);
}
```

It says in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename#basename) how you should use the `basename` function:

```
my $filename = basename($path);
my $filename = basename($path, @suffixes);
```

> This function is provided for compatibility with the Unix shell command basename(1). It does NOT always return the file name portion of a path as you might expect. To be safe, if you want the file name portion of a path use fileparse().

> `basename()` returns the last level of a filepath even if the last level is clearly directory. In effect, it is acting like `pop()` for paths. This differs from `fileparse()`'s behaviour.

```
# Both return "bar"
basename("/foo/bar");
basename("/foo/bar/");
```

---

You should note that by removing the full paths from the glob, that you cannot access the files if you cannot also `chdir` to their location, like you said you could not do "for a reason". So this whole exercise might be quite pointless for you.

You might like to look at [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) which does a similar thing, recursively, and automatically allows you to select basename or full name. Like an all in one package.

Comment: Thanks @TLP for the answer. Your first part is a workaround and is useful.

Comment: @PPP Well, its not a workaround, that is how you use `basename()` on array elements in a non-destructive way.

Comment: Yes @TLP, but I found \@toolic way more compact. It's one of the same thing though.

Comment: @PPP It is hardly "way more compact". It is using the `map` function. But as you say, its the same basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only ever interested in the filenames within that directory, then just read the directory directly:

```
my $path = '.....';
opendir my $dir, $path or die "opendir($path): $!\n";
my @kkarray = sort grep !/^\.\.?$/, readdir $dir;
close $dir;
```